# How do I vertically align multiple text next to an image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="width: 150px">  
<div style="padding: 5px">
   <img src="http://xenforomods.info/styles/Silent/xenforo/browser/announcementIcon.png" width="50px" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span style="font-size:10px;">Some text here jasjsjsjsjsjjsjsjsjsjsjsjs</span>
</div>      
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rAGf/

Which shows an image like:

[image]

How can I center multiple lines next to this image, so that this `jasj....` does not go down the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this link

Give `float:left` style for image tag

http://jsfiddle.net/2rAGf/12/

Comment: float: left seems to be insufficient on its own. If the "Some text here" tag happened to just be two short words they would appear higher than vertical center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left` for both elements `img` and `span`. But you need to extend the width of he container (div) a bit, like: `250px`..instead of `150px`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the display-property of the outer div to "inline", like this:

```
<div style="width: 150px; display: inline;">  
<div style="padding: 5px">
   <img src="http://xenforomods.info/styles/Silent/xenforo/browser/announcementIcon.png" width="50px" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span style="font-size:10px;">Some text here jasjsjsjsjsjjsjsjsjsjsjsjs</span>
</div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the width of the text span and set the display to inline-block.

```
<div style="">  
<div style="padding: 5px">
   <img src="http://xenforomods.info/styles/Silent/xenforo/browser/announcementIcon.png" width="50px" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span style="font-size:10px; width:100px; display:inline-block;">Some text here jasjsjsjsjsjjsjsjsjsjsjsjs</span>
</div>      
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. In the fiddle provide, it's not perfectly centered. Add many more lines of text and it fails altogether.